# Move 1 file at a time based off timestamp using windows batch utility

Tags: windows, command-line, batch-file

I am trying to build a .bat file to move files from 1 folder into another one, based off of the oldest time-stamped file.

**Folder 1**:

```
Filename:        Date Modified:
test1.dat        5/12/2014 4:03pm
test2.dat        5/12/2014 4:04pm
```

The goal is to move the oldest file into **Folder 2**. Currently, my batch file below moves everything from folder 1 to folder 2, obviously because I don't have any time related code entered.

```
set Delay=10
move /-y "C:\Users\bingersoll001\Desktop\folder1\*.dat" "C:\Users\bingersoll001\Desktop\folder2"
timeout 10 /nobreak
call move.bat
```

Is there any way to accomplish this?

Comment: Which version of Windows? If it's reasonably recent, PowerShell is far easier.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you're using a relatively recent version of Windows (Vista or newer), I'd recommend you use PowerShell. It's much easier to do this kind of task there. You can also install PS on XP if you want.

```
gci | where {!$_.PSIsContainer} | sort LastWriteTime | select -f 1 | move -destination "C:\some\path\"
```

Or if you have PS 3.0/Windows 8:

```
gci -file | sort LastWriteTime | select -f 1 | move -destination "C:\some\path\"
```

#### Explanation:

- `gci` - Short for `Get-ChildItem`. It gets all files in a directory. `-file` makes it return files only, no directories. Analogous to `dir` and `ls`.
- `where` - Short for `Where-Object`. Filter the input by some condition. Before PS 3.0, `-file` didn't exist for `gci`, so it was necessary to use `where` filter.
- `sort` - Short for `Sort-Object` ascending by `LastWriteTime`.
- `select` - Short for `Select-Object`. Only take the first (`-f 1`) result.
- `move` - Short for `Move-Item`. Moves the result of the previous pipeline into the `-destination` folder.

Further help available with the `help <commandname>` command.

Answer (score 2):

The following batch script will move the file with the oldest write time from its original folder to the target one.

```
@echo off
setlocal

set source=C:\Users\bingersoll001\Desktop\folder1
set dest=C:\Users\bingersoll001\Desktop\folder2
set exts=*.dat

pushd "%source%"

for /f "delims=" %%G in ('dir /b /o:d %exts%') do (
move /-y "%%~G" "%dest%"
goto :break
)
:break

popd
endlocal & exit /b
```

### How it works

1. Turn off the command echoing feature for a less verbose output.

   ```
   @echo off
   ```
2. Make any change to environment variables local to the batch file.

   ```
   setlocal
   ```
3. Set a new local variable called `source` which holds the source folder path.

   ```
   set source=C:\Users\bingersoll001\Desktop\folder1
   ```
4. Similar to the previous line, define a new local variable for the destination folder.

   ```
   set dest=C:\Users\bingersoll001\Desktop\folder2
   ```
5. Creates a new local variable which contains the file extensions to filter. Multiple extensions have to be separated by a semicolon (`;`).

   ```
   set exts=*.dat
   ```
6. Change the current working folder.

   ```
   pushd "%source%"
   ```
7. Execute the `dir /b /o:d /t:w %exts%` command, and then parse its output. The `/b` parameter, the `dir` command displays a bare file list with no heading or summary; `/o:d` makes the list sorted by date/time (oldest first). By default files are sorted by their last write time. The `"delims="` part is required to avoid issues with file paths containing space characters.

   ```
   for /f "delims=" %%G in ('dir /b /o:d %exts%') do (
   ```
8. Move the file to the destination folder.

   ```
   move /-y "%%~G" "%dest%"
   ```
9. No other file needs to be processed; jump to the `:break` label thus exiting the `for` loop.

   ```
   goto :break
   ```
10. Restore the previous working folder and exit.

    ```
    popd
    endlocal & exit /b
    ```

### Further reading

- [Command-Line Reference](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc754340.aspx)